# OAuth2.0 Authentication for Google API's without using Account Manager on Android

Tags: android, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-api-java-client, accountmanager

I would like to know if it is possible to authenticate user accounts on Android for Google API's without Account Manager handling it. I do not want to add the account to the device but would want it such that email id and password are stored in the app database and the authentication performed by retrieving the stored id and password. Is there any such alternative which allows me to authenticate by entering the id and password manually or any such third party alternatives which help me do that cos I am really stuck at this junction. Any pointers will be gladly welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would *completely* defeat the purpose of OAuth. The whole idea is that you **DO NOT** store the credentials in your app. So, the answer is no.

Comment: I am actually trying to develop an app which stores the credentials of a group of people and then automatically query Google API's for the required information. If I add the users accounts to the device, that would defeat my purpose cos android allows account information to be synced to the device which I want to avoid.

Comment: Since Google API's use OAuth2.0 for authentication, using Accounts Manager is the only way through which I can authenticate it. Is there any alternative to this problem cos I read that Accounts Manager has been the recommended method from SDK 2.0, so there must have been a way before that? Am I wrong? Or is there ANY other alternative to this problem?

Comment: Not that I know of, SDK 1.0 is deprecated.